# Generating list of string from keywords in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of strings which are some keywords like:

```
list1 = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]
```

I want to create a list which merge these together  randomly like:

```
list2= ["ABC" , "DEF" , "GHI" , "ABCDEF", "ABCGHI", ...]
```

### How is it possible?

More info:
knowing that itertools.combination module do the job like:

```
from itertools import combinations
list = ["ABC", "DEF" , "GHI"]
["".join(a) for a in combinations(list, 2)]
```

will do a combination like:

["ABCDEF", "ABCGHI", "DEFGHI"]
but I want all possible answers:
which can be done like:

```
["".join(a) for a in combinations(list, 1)]
["".join(a) for a in combinations(list, 2)]
["".join(a) for a in combinations(list, 3)]
```

will print:

```
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
['ABCDEF', 'ABCGHI', 'DEFGHI']
['ABCDEFGHI']
```

Comment: take a look at itertools

Comment: how long is list2? is it all possible combinations ? what about merging: is it at most 2 of the elements ?

Comment: @Abdallah merging all, which returns ABCDEFGHI at the end